# Binding namespaced view models in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to give some structure to my knockout code by using namespaces:

```
var Namespace = Namespace || {};

Namespace.ViewModel = function(){
  self = this;
  self.test = function() {
    console.log('test');
  }
};

Namespace.Start = function(){
  var viewModel = Namespace.ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  return viewModel;
};
```

The problem is that to bind it to a view I have to use namespace like `<li data-bind="click: Namespace.test"></li>`, is this the expected behaviour or I can somehow only use `data-bind="click: test"`, or perhaps there is a better way to do this without using something like require.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing has a different cause. Your `Namespace.ViewModel` is a [constructor function](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) and should be called like this:

```
var viewModel = new Namespace.ViewModel();
```

Notice the `new` keyword.

You can see it working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbhh8/). It allows you to just write:

```html
<button data-bind="click: test">Test Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem. But you should write `var viewModel = new Namespace.ViewModel();` (with `new`) and there are no reasons to `return viewModel;`. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/6SWJc/).